# What does a constant with linear trend (‘ct’) line look like?

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, arima

In the SARIMA model, the trend parameter can be specified:

- 'n' indicates no trend;
- 'c' indicates constant;
- 't' indicates a linear trend with time;
- 'ct' indicates a constant with linear trend.

The first three are very straightforward, but what does a constant with linear trend look like?

Comment: "*...can be specified*..." where?

Comment: @Julius Vainora Here is the description on the API: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's a linear trend where the intercept is nonzero. Here are some examples of the trends:

- **c**: trend = constant, where the "constant" value is like "10" or "1.2345"
- **t**: trend = t, where t is the observation number, t = 1, 2, 3, ...
- **ct**: trend = constant + t, where the "constant" value is like "10" or "1.2345" and t is the observation number, t = 1, 2, 3, ...

Finally, in the `nc` case, trend = 0

Comment: So 't' is like y = ax where a doesn't equal to 0, and 'ct' is like y = ax + b where a and b both don't equal to 0?